# add custom link after create account link magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to add custom link after create an account link in top header but not able to do that, please help

thanks in advance

**my default.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Test\Pro\Block\Template" name="custom_link_social_after" template="Test_Pro::html/custom_social_link_after.phtml" after="register-link"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: which is the parent theme you are extending?

Comment: using porto theme

Comment: which is the parent theme of porto theme? you can see it in app/design/frontend/`<portoVendor>`/`porttoThemeName`/theme.xml

Comment: its using Magento/blank

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Test\Pro\Block\Template" name="custom_link_social_after" template="Test_Pro::html/custom_social_link_after.phtml" after="register-link"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

To

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom_social_link_after" template="Test_Pro::custom_social_link_after.phtml" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Your link label</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">your-link-path</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Your phtml file
`<your Test_Pro module dir>/view/frontend/templates/custom_social_link_after.phtml`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 */
?>
<li>
    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getHref()) ?>"
        <?php if ($title = $block->getTitle()) : ?> title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__($title)) ?>"<?php endif;?>>
        <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($block->getLabel())) ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: how to add file link to this xml?

Comment: do you mean to assign a phtml template file?

Comment: yes wan to assign a phtml file

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look carefully.

Comment: its not working

Comment: Please double-check the xml file to make sure it contains the current XML code in my answer as I updated it. Your phtml file path should be app/code/Test/Pro/view/frontend/templates/custom_social_link_after.phtml. Remember clear cache after that.

Comment: already checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139791/discussion-between-tu-van-and-nihal-malik).